# Monodevelop does not show iPhone application option

Tags: iphone, monodevelop

I am using the latest iPhone IDK, Mono, monotouch and Monodevelop as of July 1, 2010. I installed on a Mac with latest version of Snow Leopard. When I open MonoDevelop, the option for an iPhone application is not listed. Also, when I use the Interface Builder and place controls (set outlets also) and save, there is not change in the related code for the xib.designer.cs. Its like the IDK (or Interface Builder) and monodevelop are not talking to each other.

Any help would greatly be appreciated...

Answer (score 4):

It appears you are not running the latest MonoDevelop.  The Interface Builder bug was fixed recently.

Comment: Clarification - the bug occurred when the xib.designer.cs files added by some project templates were not "grouped" with the corresponding xib file. Existing projects can be fixed by removing the files from the project and re-adding them.